# Angular ng-class doesn't finish animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I browsed a lot of the documentation and StackOverflow, as far as I can tell ng-class should support animations, therefore I am probably doing something wrong in my code.
I'm trying to shrink my navbar height when scrolled down, but if I scroll the mouse wheel just once, the animation gets stuck half way and doesn't finish. When I use the mouse and drag the scrollbar down smoothly, the animation finishes just fine.

Everything is working, except for the animation getting stuck, when scrolling only once.

This is my code for the animation:

```
.controller('MainController', function ($window, $scope) {
    $scope.pageYOffset = 0;

    $scope.isScrolledDown = function () {
        return ($scope.pageYOffset >= 1);
    };

    $window.onscroll = function() {
        $scope.pageYOffset = this.pageYOffset;
        $scope.$digest();
    };
})
```

I call the isScrolledDown() function in ng-class like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" ng-class="{navshrinked:isScrolledDown()}">
```

In my CSS class, I have `navbar` and `navmin` class with different heights and transitions.

Using the stable version of AngularJS (1.4.8)

Comment: What I found out by testing so far, is that when I add the exact same code somewhere else in my body, they both magically start working just fine. This is very odd and frustrating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and thinking, I've finally found the problem, which oddly hasn't been addressed as much as it should have. It has to do with `fixed` and `absolute` position on Google Chrome. This problem was already reported more than a year ago, but still has not been fixed.

Mozilla Firefox has enabled smooth scrolling by default, but on Google Chrome and perhaps other browsers, you must set a flag for it. That is, if you want to fix the issue on client side, which is obviously a **horrible** solution.

So, if you try to apply a `transition` on a `fixed` or `absolute` positioned element, you'll most likely end up with the same result.

To fix that, you have to specify some custom rules on the element that you want to transition:

```
 -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
      -o-column-break-inside: avoid;
     -ms-column-break-inside: avoid;
         column-break-inside: avoid;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I hope people see and find this question/answer useful, as it's quite a big deal and by the lack of information on this subject, I assume not many people know about it as well.